# How to create a search engine with filters?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, search-engine

I'm trying to create an online search for a particular set of literature/quotes/etc from a spiritual organization, 
and while the number of items (mostly PDF, HTML, or plain text) that can be searched is limited,
I wanted to provide comprehensive search filters (Kayak.com style).

That means my data will need to be organized in such a way that it's easy to filter by author name, source type (whether it's a book, speech, quote, etc), 
when, and where, and other filters.  That means, each literature item will have to have this "additional information" tied with it.

My question is, how do I go about building this search engine?  I have heard of Lucerine, and 
also recently discovered Searcharoo, a .NET library for searching, which will index all my PDF files located in a local directory.

What I'm wondering is if I should use Searcharoo, or if I should simply create my own database which stores the filepath, and query
a column that contains the text of the PDF file.  Or can I use Searcharoo, or something similar, and still 
be able to tag each indexed file with additional information stored in the DB? Or should I take a completely different approach?

I'd appreciate any input on this...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've heard [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) was designed for this but honestly I've never used it before.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) for making full-text indexes that contain additional metadata. It's stable, quick, and reasonably well documented, if you don't mind using a Java port.